# Derivative of f, such that f<-function(x){x^2} (or similar) without yacas

Tags: r, function, derivative

I need to find derivative of function defined like

```
f<-function(x){x^2}
```

After that I want to have a derivative function `g`, such that I would be able to get something like:

```
  g(5)       # entered 
  10          # answer
```

without Yacas or similar heavy software. I find it surprising that R can find the derivative of `x^2`, but there is no way to differentiate `f<-function(x){x^2}`.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
f<-function(x){x^2}
g<-Deriv(f,"x")
```

*I got an error:*

```
 Error in list2env(list(), NULL, <environment>) : 
 names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

I have also tried this:

```
> f1<-'x^2'
> g<-Deriv(f1,"x")
> g
#Result:
"2*x"
```

Can I transform my function f to a one like f1 and reverse the process? 
Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your function as an expression:

```
f <- expression(x^2)
```

Such an expression can be treated like a function by using `eval()`:

```
#> eval(f,list(x=2))
#[1] 4
```

In this case, the advantage of an expression instead of a function is that the former allows for the use of symbolic calculus to obtain the first derivative:

```
g <- D(f,"x")
#> g
#2 * x
```

To evaluate this expression of the first derivative (more precisely its class is a `call`), you can use the same syntax as was done before for `f`:

```
#> eval(g,list(x=5))
#[1] 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a one line body and a function of a single variable `x`:

```
f <- function(x) x^2
g <- f
body(g) <- D(body(f), "x")
```

giving:

```
> g
function (x) 
2 * x
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but if i write f<-function(x){x^2}, instead of f<-function(x) x^2 , than it doesn`t: Error in D(body(f), "x") : Function '`{`' is not in the derivatives table.

Comment: Right. { is not supported.

Comment: To free function out of {}, it is helpful to use f<-f[[2]] .